# Visual Studio 2017 looking for DLL rather than a LIB

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, lib

A C/C++-Win32-project used to compile, link and run just fine using Visual Studio 2010. This project uses a 3rd party library XYZ.LIB that comes as a (statically linked) object library (not an import library).

I transferred this project to Visual Studio 2017 and while it still compiles, it won't run anymore. Upon starting the programm, a message pops up telling that XYZ.DLL (!) is missing. I already added XYZ.LIB under Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies. I actually don't have the XYZ.DLL and VS2010 never complained about needing a DLL rather than the provided LIB.
How can I get VS2017 to use the regular LIB rather than looking for a DLL with the same name ?

Comment: So what's wrong about that ? It's actually an object library, otherwise VS2010 would not have been able to link and run the program. Also there is no XYZ.DLL and has never been.
Oops, the comment I replied to is gone now ...

Comment: *Upon starting the programm, a message pops up telling that XYZ.DLL (!) is missing* -- Whatever your compiler switches were for VS 2010, they were obviously changed in VS 2017.  Does XYZ have a DLL option, and you are erroneously compiling your application to use the DLL?  A lot of third-party libraries have both options, and depending on compiler switches, preprocessor values, etc, the app is built to either use the DLL or static library.